# Excel - Change colour of cell with max number of random selections

Tags: excel, max, bold

Say I have 200 rows of data, mixed with text and numbers on excel such as below:

```
name | surname | dummy number | number 1 | house name | number 2 | father name | number 3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joe  | Smith   | 1            | 0.123    | Test       | 0.456    | Paul        | 0.789
Mark | Jones   | 32           | 0.321    | Test       | 0.555    | Michael     | 0.777
Luke | McKenney| 12           | 0.888    | Test       | 0.121    | Hank        | 0.333

and so on for around 200-300 columns.
```

Let's say I want to make the maximum number (from number 1/2/3) bold in each row. I could do it using a conditional formatting, however it would take me forever since I have a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be done with conditional formatting.

Assuming the numbers are in columns D, F and H and the data starts in row 2.

1. Select the rows of data from row 2 down, with example data that's A2:H4.
2. Goto Format>Conditional formatting...
3. Select Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4. Enter this formula.

```
    =D2=MAX($D2,$F2,$H2)
```

5. Click Format... and set the formatting you want.
6. Click OK.

This is how the supplied data looks after the formatting is applied.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works, however only with 1 row. I need it to work with multiple rows. Thanks.

Comment: Can you send me a message please? I would like to show you what I'm doing, as I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you follow the steps I outlined in the answer? Note, I've adjusted step 1 to make it easier to select the data to format.

Comment: Let me show you a sample from the table that I am working with. https://imgur.com/a/qhYONGv The columns I need to get the maximum value per row are: F13, H13, J13, L13, N13, P13. I managed to do it with just one row and this formula: =F13=MAX($F13, $H13, $J13, $L13, $N13, $P13) but I didn't manage to do it with the whole table. Thanks

Comment: What range did you select when applying the conditional formatting? It should be F13:P21, where 21 is the last row of data.

Comment: I selected all the data per column, since I do not want the "1-P" included with the conditional statement. Therefore, I chose the data from columns F13, H13, J13, L13, N13 and P13.

Comment: I have also tried doing the formula when selecting all the rows, but it keeps on marking the "1-A"s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230457/discussion-between-norie-and-johnny-long).

Answer (score 0):

This VBA script will bold maximum value in every row from row 2 in active sheet.

```vb
Sub bold_max_in_row()
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim max
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Rows()
  max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(r)
  For Each c In r.Cells
    If c = max Then c.Font.Bold = True
  Next
Next
End Sub
```